# does sequence of where condition changes the result in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, temp-tables

I am getting a unique problem in one query .

```
insert into #tempclasssearch
            SELECT cc.Id, B.ScheduleId, 10, Lc.Id LocationId, Lc.GroupId, cc.CategoryId,CCSC.SubCategoryId,cc.RegistrationId
            from Event CC Inner join Batches B
            On Cc.Id = B.ClassCreativeId
            Inner Join Venues V On B.VenueId = V.ID
            Inner Join loc Lc On V.LocId = Lc.id
            Inner join EventSubCategories CCSC on CC.Id = CCSC.EventId
            inner join PackageSubscriptions p on p.userId = cc.userId
            Where 
            p.SubscriptionStatus = 1 and 
            ((@GroupId = 0) or (@GroupId is not null and Lc.GroupId = @GroupId))
            and ((@LocationId = 0) or (@LocationId is not null and Lc.Id = @LocationId))
            and ((@TargetCityId is null) or (@TargetCityId is not null and Lc.TargetCityId = @TargetCityId))                        
            and ((@CategoryId = 0) or (@CategoryId is not null and cc.CategoryId = @CategoryId))
            and ((@SubCategoryId = 0) or (@SubCategoryId is not null and ccsc.SubCategoryId = @SubCategoryId))
            and cc.UserStatus = 1 and cc.PublishStatus = 3 and B.StartDate >= @StartDateTime -- and B.StartDateTime > @StartDateTime
            and ((@EndDateTime is null) or (@EndDateTime is not null and B.StartDate <= @EndDateTime
            and p.StartDateTimeUtc <= GETUTCDATE() 
            and p.EndDateTimeUtc >= GETUTCDATE()
```

The problem is that if I place this condition `p.SubscriptionStatus = 1` at the end then it doesn't execute this condition while if I place it as first condition it does.

I don't know what is happening :(

let me know if you guys have any idea ....

Comment: last third line i.e. and ((@EndDateTime is null) or (@EndDateTime is not null and B.StartDate <= @EndDateTime is missing a ")" bracket

Answer (score 0):

Parenthesis missing at the end

and ((@EndDateTime is null) or (@EndDateTime is not null and B.StartDate <= @EndDateTime